# How to transfer tokens from one network to another using web3.py?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

Here is contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x609c690e8f7d68a59885c9132e812eebdaaf0c9e#code
As I understand it, it has a method for swapping from erc-20 to trc-20 - swapAndBridge.

How to use this method correctly to transfer tokens from one network to another?Can someone tell me exactly how the process of bridging from one network to another works and help me understand it?